# Is your table of integrals complete?

Tags: integration

A course in integral calculus consists largely of manipulations to transform an elementary integrand into something that has a known [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) antiderivative.

I'm wondering: can I be confident that, if this *can* be done for a given integrand, the known list of such tricks suffices to do it?

Or, on the other hand, is there a proof that the list can never be complete?

Comment: if I understood correctly you are asking if there is a finite number of functions such that any primitive can be written as a composition of them. I think the answer is no.

Comment: This question has been studied in connection with symbolic integration by compter programs.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm

Comment: Some special functions are defined as an antiderivative of a pre-existing function. So, when the antiderivative of a function cannot be expressed on closed form, a new special function is likely to be defined. (Function defined by an integral). For example, think at an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ before the logarithmic function be defined. https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-spéciales

Comment: @saulspatz I think your comment is really an answer. Presumably that algorithm (new to me thank you) encapsulates the "list of tricks" the OP has in mind.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, I imagine it does, but there's more to it than that.  Apparently algebraic geometry is somehow involved.  An algebraic geometer friend tried to explain it to me many years ago, but my ignorance proved too much for him.  (I'm just assuming it's the same or a related algorithm from the time frame. This was over 30 years ago,  and  my memory is hazy.)  I didn't feel like posting an answer, because I really don't know what I'm talking about.